# Placing a UITextField in the center of the view

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, alignment

I have a `UITextField` and I want to center this field on the center of the view. Any ideas?

```
usernameField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, 200, 28)];
```

Instead of `CGRectMake(some numbers)` - I want to place it in the center of the view.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can directly assign it the center of the desired view:

```
usernameField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, 200, 28)];
usernameField.center = myView.center;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
userNameField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 28)];
userNameField.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetWidth(someView.bounds)/2.0f, CGRectGetHeight(someView.bounds)/2.0f);
```

Where someView is the superview of userNameField.

Comment: That's a little convoluted but it works. Using the center is much clearer code.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the view's center property?

```
userNameField.center = parentViewField.center;
```

Comment: This assumes parentView is fullScreen. Center is in frame space, not bounds space.

Comment: No it doesn't. It centers the subview in the parent view - which is what the question asks.

Comment: "The center is specified within the coordinate system of its superview and is measured in points."  If you have 3 views deep, and your'e trying to center the 3rd view in the 2nd view. Your method will center it in the first.